# Error for math equation

Tags: equations

Latex is throwing an error for the following, but not indicating why - any help?

```
\begin{equation}
\[A_p = \frac{|r-s|}{r+s-2} \text{ for } r+s < 2 \text{ and } A_p(1,1) = 0 ~~~\]
\end{equation}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add the complete error message to your question  and  make your code snippet compilable ...

Comment: It's because `\begin{equation}` by itself starts math-mode, as well as the `\[...\]` pair. If you want a numbered equation use `\begin{equation}`, otherwise, `\[...\]`, but not both.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as having been solved in one of the comments.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `\[` and `\]` if you already are inside an equation tag.